# Generating QR codes in google-spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, qr-code, urlencode

I have a simple question about generating QR codes with google-spreadhseet.
I am using google's API call

```
=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&A3)
```

This works fine.
Where `A3` is a persons first name.

I have their last name in `A4` but when I try:

```
=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&(A3+A4))
```

or

```
=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&
(CONCATENATE(A3, " ", A4)))
```

The QR box is blank.

How can I generate a QR code from both the first and last name without having to create another field.

Answer (score 2):

Simple as that:

```
=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&A3&A4)
```

Note that this will only work if A3 and A4 only contain unreserved URL characters; otherwise you need [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) as explained in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30909885/4676295).

Answer (score 0):

See this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30909885/4676295) which gives a full explanation on how to encode data to create the QR code and gives an example on how to take information row by row from a sheet and automatically build QR codes.