# Generating QR code in google sheets that holds up to 200 characters of text with spaces

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlencode

In google sheets I have a cell that contains up to 200 or 250 characters (including spaces). I need to create a QR code in the cell beside it....

```
=if(isblank(E2),"",image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&E2))
```

this works if the text contains no space in cell E2... what if I want it to hold the contents 'I wish I could get the QR code generator to work with spaces'. How could I generate the QR code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Awesome!!!! Can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Formula

```
=if(isblank(E2),"",image(
"https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&SUBSTITUTE(E2," ","%20")
))
```

## Explanation

URL strings should be encoded, so the space should be replaced by `%20`.

## See also

- [Generating QR codes in google-spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683867/generating-qr-codes-in-google-spreadsheet/24760800#24760800)

Comment: could I also put a tab between cell E2 and cell E3 and make into one QR CODE?         =if(isblank(E2),"",image(
"https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&SUBSTITUTE(E2," ","%20")
))&"%09"&if(isblank(E3),"",image(
"https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&SUBSTITUTE(E3," ","%20")
))........ Would something like that even work???? Thank you in advance!!!!  If not, how to generate a tab QR code?  ="%09" doesn't work.

Comment: The fastest way to find out if a formula will work is by trying it by oneself. If after trying it and searching for the solution you don't find by yourself, please post a new question.